# How to make the same API call multiple times on a page with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, api, jquery-ui

This is an API JS that fetches data from an array and used for a typeahead search with jQuery UI `autocomplete`, but there's a limit in the system of 400 records to be fetched at once, in order to fetch the full record list (let's say 4000), now I need to run this API call at least 10 times, how would the approach be like?

I read [this](https://dev.to/raviojha/javascript-making-multiple-api-calls-the-right-way-2b29) article, but couldn't figure out how to use it with the current code.

```js
var eventList = [];
var getEvents = function() {
  system123.api.request({
    api: 'apiName',
    data: 'methods',
    callback: {
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.getTeameventsResponse.totalNumberResults === "0") {
          // no search results
          console.log("no events");
        } else {
          events = system123.utils.ensureArray(response.getTeameventsResponse.teamevent);
          console.log("events", events);
          $(events).each(function(i, event) {
            eventList.push(event.name);
          });
        }
      },
      error: function(response) {
        console.log(response.errorResponse.message);
      }
    }
  });
};

$(function() {
  getEvents();

  $("#eventName").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
      response($.grep(eventList, function(item) {
        return matcher.test(item);
      }));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't do this. 4000 records is far too many for the UI to handle, this is why the limit-per-request exists. If you're trying to show suggestions for an auto-complete field, do the filtering server side, then return the top N results to be displayed in the UI control

Comment: Thanks, I should've also have mentioned this is in a CMS system, so I won't have access to anything on the server side.

Comment: In which case, ask whoever has access to the CMS to create an endpoint to allow you to do the filtering server side. I can tell you with certainty that making 10 AJAX requests, collating all the data in to a single array, then filtering it on the server side is not a workable solution.